# How do I tell if an HttpResponse is already closed?

Tags: dart, dart-io

Using Dart's `dart:io` library, how can I tell if an `HttpResponse` is already closed?

I couldn't find a hint in the API docs: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpResponse.html

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Stab in the dark here, but would `connectionInfo` being `null` mean that the `HttpResponse` has finished?

Otherwise, I guess you could set a "closed" bool variable from the Future returned by `done`, and test whether it's set before processing the response?

```dart
HttpResponse response = ...;
bool closed = false;
response.done.then((_) => closed = true);

if (!closed) {
  ...
}
```

But I'm not sure whether you could ever do this early enough, would depend on the scenario.